# Unable to set datetime format in MVC 4 using data annotations

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datetime, asp.net-mvc-4, datetime-format

I will try everything but not working this(**dd/MM/yyyy**) date format, this always gate **mm/dd/yyyy**

```
[Display(Name = "Release Date")]
[DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
public Nullable<DateTime> release_date { get; set; }
```

Razor view

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.release_date)
```

Using DateTime Template.

```
@model Nullable<System.DateTime>
@if (Model.HasValue)
{
    @Html.TextBox("", String.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", Model.Value))
}
else
{
    @Html.TextBox("", String.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", DateTime.Now))
}
@{
    string name = ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix;
    string id = name.Replace(".", "_");
}
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#@id").datepicker({
                dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
                showStatus: true,
                showWeeks: true,
                highlightWeek: true,
                numberOfMonths: 1,
                showAnim: "scale",
                showOptions: {
                    origin: ["top", "left"]
                }
          });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: From the image it looks like the date is `dd/mm/yyyy`

Comment: Note that "mm" is minutes, aside from anything else - so you probably mean "dd/MM/yyyy".

Comment: yes this is (24/08/2012) dd/MM/yyyy

Comment: eh?, so what month is 24, I thought a year only had 12 months, what calendar are you using

Comment: i will also try MM or mm and DD or dd but not working

Comment: @saj 24 is that date. He wants dd/MM/yyyy. Read the question :)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You missed 2 things here:

```
DataFormatString="{0:dd/MM/yyyy}"; //It is dd/MM/yyyy instead of dd/mm/yyyy
```

and you also need:

```
ApplyFormatInEditMode=true
```

Try to use this:

```
[Display(Name = "Release Date")]
[DataType(DataType.Date), DisplayFormat( DataFormatString="{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode=true )]
public Nullable<DateTime> release_date { get; set; }
```

Comment: What do you mean DataType(DataType.Date) is working? When I try this, I get a calendar to pick a date, but when I jump to the next field on the form, the date is still shown as mm/dd/yyyy.

Comment: I need to use dot "." as seperator. [DataType(DataType.Date), DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd.MM.yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)] Not working? What can i do?

Comment: To get this to work, I had to escape the date format as @"{0:dd\/MM\/yyyy}"

Answer (score 5):

`{0:dd/mm/yyyy}` should be `{0:dd/MM/yyyy}` because `mm` means minutes, not months:

```
[Display(Name = "Release Date")]
[DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
public Nullable<DateTime> release_date { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use data-annotation. when display it good. but when edit mode. it still use server format (culture setting)
DisplayFormat: like it name, only for display

There are some option to solve.
 - paste to server as string with your favorite format
 - write customer bindding
 - Setting globalization in web.config
for Format : dd/MM/yyy i using setting bellow

```
<system.web>
    <globalization culture="en-GB"/>
....
```