# Validate DateFormat In Mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a property ExpiredDate define in MVC

```
[Required]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")]
        public DateTime? ExpirationDate { get; set; }
```

I want to Validate if Date on a page is not in correct format.
The format of date I am using is *`MM/dd/yyyy`*.

Comment: MVC will validate according to formate by default, if you need client side validation, you need to turn on unobtrusive javascript  on you application

Comment: Set the `ApplyFormatInEditMode` property to `true` in the `DisplayFormatAttribute`

Comment: @asawyer Sir it doesnot validate and page postback. i want to stop the postback and want to show the format message.

Comment: Please also read the first comment: You need to turn on unobtrusive javascript on your application

Comment: @ Kenneth how to do that.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You should use the [**`DataType`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.datatypeattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) attribute with [**`DataType.Date`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.datatype(v=vs.110).aspx). Both of which are in the [`System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations(v=vs.110).aspx) namespace and can be used like this:

```cs
[Required]
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")]
public DateTime? ExpirationDate { get; set; }
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12109007/unable-to-set-datetime-format-in-mvc-4-using-data-annotations) also includes some more attributes.

**Update**: To enable client-side validation in ASP.NET MVC4, you need to do this:

1. Add the jquery.validation plugin to the footer

   ```xml
   <%: Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js") %>
   <%: Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js") %>
   ```
2. Add this to web.config

   ```xml
   <appSettings>
     <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
     <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
   </appSettings>
   ```
3. Use this css when using `@Html.ValidationMessageFor()` so that it is initially hidden and displays via the javascript validation

   ```css
   /* styles for validation helpers */
   .field-validation-error {
       color: #e80c20;
       font-weight: bold;
   }

   .field-validation-valid {
       display: none;
   }

   input.input-validation-error {
       border: 1px solid #e80c20;
   }

   input[type="checkbox"].input-validation-error {
       border: 0 none;
   }

   .validation-summary-errors {
       color: #e80c20;
       font-weight: bold;
       font-size: 1.1em;
   }

   .validation-summary-valid {
       display: none;
   }
   ```

Comment: To enable client-side validation, just add the jquery.validate plugin to your footer like this: `<%: Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js") %> <%:Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js") %>`

Comment: Sir @truemedia, i have tried this code 
  [Required(ErrorMessage="ss")]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true,DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")]
        public DateTime? date { get; set; }

Comment: the page still postback even if it doesnt contain any date and also postback when i put a simple integer 345

Comment: Did you add the client-side validation javascript files to the view? Those two javascript files (jquery.validate.min.js and jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js) should be included in the MVC default project template.

Comment: One more thing, you need to add this to your web.config to enable validation: `<appSettings><add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" /><add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" /></appSettings>`

Comment: Thanks sir, but by using   [RegularExpression(@"^(([0-2]\d|[3][0-1])\.([0]\d|[1][0-2])\.[2][0]\d{2})$",ErrorMessage = "End Date should be in MM/dd/yyyy format")] it works for me

Answer (score 13):

Custom validation date format must be solved manually.

Client validation issues can occur because of MVC bug (even in MVC 5) in *jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js* which **does not accept date/datetime format in any way**. It is not caused by datepicker nor browsers. Unfortunately you have to solve it manually.

**My finally working solution:**

You have to include before:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.js")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/moment.js")
```

You can install moment.js using:

```
Install-Package Moment.js
```

And then you can finally add fix for date format parser:

```
$(function () {
    $.validator.methods.date = function (value, element) {
        return this.optional(element) || moment(value, "DD.MM.YYYY", true).isValid();
    }
});
```

Comment: for example in 
... 
<head>
  <script>
   .. here
  </script>
</head>
...

Answer (score -5):

You can use validation like:

```
[Required]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:d}")]
        public DateTime? ExpirationDate { get; set; }
```

I think it will work

Comment: No sir page postback if i type 12345 and submit the form or any invalid date.