# Allow Invalid Date in ASP.NET Core API Service

Tags: serialization, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

We have a API service that we are updating and we converted some date objects from strings to DateTime objects. In the old code we tested the string if it would parse to a data time or not. If it was a bad formatted string, it would assign DateTime.Min and continue on. Now customers are sending in bad dates and it blows up since the serialization happens outside our code (MVC Controller). I am trying to find some way that when serializing a DateTime object, if it can not parse it, it just returns DateTime.Min instead of blowing up the call.

Here is the response from the API Call.

```
{
  "date": [
    "Could not convert string to DateTime: Invalid Date. Path 'date', line 3, position 24."
  ]
}
```

**===== UPDATE =====**

I finally found somewhere that recommended a custom JsonConverter. I finally got something that works, but there is little out there so if there is something I could do better I am all ears.

**Custom Converter**

```
  public class DateConverter : JsonConverter
  {
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
      try
      {
        return DateTime.Parse(reader.Value.ToString());
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
        return DateTime.MinValue;
      }
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
      return objectType == typeof(DateTime);
    }
  }
```

**DTO Class**

```
public class Request
  {

    [JsonConverter(typeof(SafeDateConverter))]
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
  }
```

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: What code would you like me to include? This error is happening before it even hits any of the code that I write. I send in bad date, it gives error. Examples of those are irrelevant. I need to figure out how to override the default settings to gracefully handle this error and unfortunately I do not know where go... hence why I am reaching out for help. I hate posting on here because everyone criticizes and is down vote happy instead of actually trying to help.

Comment: "I am trying to find some way that when serializing a DateTime object, if it can not parse it, it just returns DateTime.Min instead of blowing up the call.". What have you tried so far?

Comment: Searching online for a solution and everywhere I find says to wrap it in a try catch which I am not able to do as explained in the question. Do I have to prove due diligence to get an answer here? I guess if you do not understand the question I would get it, but if I am asked a question, if I understand the question I answer it.

Comment: It is hard to help without seeing any code. Can you show what your controller action looks like?

Comment: I can, but I am having a hard time figuring out why it would help to post code that is not effecting the issue. The issue is Newtonsoft and how it serializes BEFORE it hits the controller. I guess I feel like that goes against the "Minimal" part by providing irrelevant code.

Comment: Please do if you don't mind - I'm still trying to grasp the situation and this is the code closest to the problem.

Comment: You could possibly use Validation with data annotations on your DTO, [like in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16567020/6939988). Then in your controller, check `if (!ModelState.IsValid)` then return your `DateTime.Min`...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach introduce another property on deserialized class of type `DateTime?` and leave original string property as it is.

```
public class Request
{
    public string Date { get; set; }

    private DateTime? _parsedDate;
    [JsonIgnore]
    public DateTime? ParsedDate 
    { 
        get { return _parsedDate; } 
        set
        {
            if (DateTime.TryParse(value, out DateTime parsed)
            {
                _parsedDate = parsed;
                return;
            }

            _parsed = null;
        }
    }       
}
```

But having custom serializer looks better, because you need change nothing in the code which already uses deserialized object.

Suggestion:
Do not use `try ... catch` for serializing bad formatted dates, there is `DateTime.TryParse` method which will do this without throwing exceptions.

And if it is not late, you can use `Nullable<DateTime>` instead of having `DateTime.Min` as "not existing" value.